# Шаблоны с переменным числом параметров и кортеж

Tags: c++

Есть такой кусочек кода:

```
...
template<typename ...Types>
double Operations::math(const OpString &op, const Types&... args)
{
    std::tuple<Types...> values{args...};
    OpAction action = Operations::getAction(op);
    switch(action)
    {
    case OpAction::plus :
        return std::get<0>(values) + std::get<1>(values);         
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

на вход метод принимает строку с операцией и операнды, например:

```
op.math("+", 2, 3);
```

или

```
op.math("√", 4);
```

При компиляции компилятор жалуется на выражение:

```
return std::get<0>(values) + std::get<1>(values);
```

`ошибка: no matching function for call to ‘get<1>(std::tuple<double>&)’ return std::get<0>(values) + std::get<1>(values); ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~`

`ошибка: static assertion failed: tuple index is in range static_assert(__i < tuple_size<tuple<>>::value, ^~~~~~~~~~~~~`

При этом если заменить 1 индекс на 0, то компилятор не жалуется:

```
return std::get<0>(values) + std::get<0>(values);
```

Также, если вместо распаковки пакета параметров захардкодить какие-то числа, то все  работает:

```
std::tuple<double, double> values{1.2, 2.5};
```

Также, если заменить кортеж на вектор, то все компилируется:

```
...
template<typename ...Types>
double Operations::math(const OpString &op, const Types&... args)
{
    std::vector<double> values{args...};
    OpAction action = Operations::getAction(op);
    switch(action)
    {
    case OpAction::plus :
        return values.at(0) + values.at(1);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Вопрос: Что не так с вариантом использования кортежа вместо вектора? Буду благодарен за помощь:)

Comment: Очевидно, что при инстанцировании `op.math("√", 4)` выражение `std::get<1>(values)` будет невалидно,       так как в кортеже будет только один элемент. И вообще вам тут не нужен ни кортеж, ни вектор.

Comment: @user7860670, при "вызове" `op.math("√", 4)` точно не будет применяться ` case OpAction::plus`. Я же поставил три точки чтобы было понятно что это вырезанный пример

Comment: Не при вызове, а при инстанцировании. Что там будет происходить во время выполнения - неизвестно, а строчка `return std::get<0>(values) + std::get<1>(values);`должна будет быть скомпилирована в любом случае.

Comment: @user7860670, не велика беда

Comment: @user7860670, то есть элементы кортежа должны быть известны во время компиляции?

Comment: Что должно произойти, если передать неправильное количество аргументов?

Comment: Во время компиляции известно их количество. И это количество проверяется во время компиляции при каждом вызове `std::get<x>` Ну и вообще, параметры шаблонов в угловых скобках *всегда* проверяются во время компиляции, и никогда - во время выполнения.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это не может произойти, так как у меня используется делегация и в "родительском" методе все это дело проверяется. Ну а так,  на всякий случай у меня кидается исключение

Comment: @user7860670, вот как! не знал(или забыл).  оказывается проблема с тем, что по задумке у меня список типов определяется динамически. Можно считать вопрос закрытым . А вам Спасибо)

Comment: Тут надо смотреть в сторону https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold (забыл дописать в первом комментарии)